# How to use code from this example in React? Can I use react-three-renderer library?Three.js+ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, three.js

I need an animation like this, which is in Three.js, only with other 3D objects instead of circles https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_particles Animation will be on the background of some interface. Also I should add some logic and import other objects instead of circles on obj format (3D-models)
Or another example https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes_tween

I'm writing code on the React. Can I insert it into the componentDidMount method and just call it as a script and continue working with it? Do I need to use this library and transfer all the logic to the React? https://github.com/toxicFork/react-three-renderer.

I copied this code (https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_particles) and called in componentDidMount (), but it can not find Stats, TWEEN. How do I transfer it to the React?

Comment: this is another example https://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes_tween

Comment: I have a simple three.js react app here which you could take a look at: https://github.com/2pha/react-three-shaders